# Stories involving Time Travel and Disease Immunity?

Tags: time-travel, history-of

When Europeans came in large numbers to the New World, the sicknesses they carried caused pandemics for Native Americans and wiped out much of the population.  I would imagine that if a time traveller went to a past or future time significantly distant, then the same kind of immunity issue would arise, and either the traveler would die of some common disease they had no immunity too, or the natives of that time would die from diseases the time traveler carried.  Have any science fiction stories dealt with this issue?  I can't think of any.

I am reading Manifold:Origin and thought about the fact that that mixing homonids from different eras would likely cause an epidemic.

What is the earliest story involving time traveling and diseases?

Comment: If I were you, I would rephrase, adding a line at the end asking "Are the any stories involving time traveling and diseases?" and still may be considered too broad for some users.

Comment: I think that, as far back as ''Time Scout'', authors have taken great care to cover the issue.

Comment: Check out Doctor Who Story 23 - [The Ark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ark_(Doctor_Who)), I think you'll find it's what you're looking for.